# Approaches or is approaching?

Tags: present-tense

Apparently *approaches* is more used than *‘is approaching’*.
Why?
In most cases *approaching*  is a continuous action so *‘is approaching’* should  be more common.

Comment: Used more where? What do you base that claim on? Note that "approaches" can be a plural noun or a verb, and are you differentiating between "is approaching", "was approaching", and participle and gerund uses of "approaching"?

Comment: "Apparently" says who? Where is your source, and if it were true in print or on social media we don't know if it's true in speech. You need to share the source of information, was it a chart, did you find the data in a dictionary?

Comment: Proper use is not decided by use count. Count how often “red” is used relative to “magenta”. If something is magenta, that’s the word you use, not “red” because it’s more common. Or count “effect” vs. “affect”. You use the one that is correct, not the one that is more common. Or “weather”, “whether” and “wether”.

Comment: To make this question answerable, please edit to give some example of context to show how these words are being used, since many words can be used in many ways. *I suspect* you mean something like "The king approaches," but that's just a guess. Voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Frequency of use isn't what determines whether a word should be used - *context* is what matters, always. So your question should really be about in which contexts each is used.

As you've stated, '...*is approaching*' is present continuous. So, as a general rule, if you're speaking about something in that tense you would use that form of the verb. We tend to speak in this tense because we talk about what is happening to us in the present.

'Approaches' is the third-person present. This is more common in novels, and scripts for TV/movies etc, because the narrator has a third-person perspective. For example, a screenplay might note that "A TRAIN APPROACHES". This may be why you have heard it is "used more", but that may not be the case in everyday speech. There are of course plenty of times we use the same form, such as in conditionals (eg "*when the train approaches you should stand back*").